# Flutter Google Maps: How can you change maptype after runtime?

Tags: google-maps, flutter, dart

I am trying to change from `normal` to `satellite` when pressing a button as shown below, but i get an error that setMapType does not exist.

```
mapController.setMapType(MapType.satellite);
```

Anyone knows what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
     import 'dart:async';

   import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

     import 'package:search_map_place/search_map_place.dart';
   import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';

   String apiKEY;

  void main() => runApp(MyApp());

 class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
   @override
     Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return MaterialApp(
        title: 'Search Map Place Demo',
        home: MapSample(),
         );
         }
      }

     class MapSample extends StatefulWidget {
     @override
     State<MapSample> createState() => MapSampleState();
    }

      class MapSampleState extends State<MapSample> {
      Completer<GoogleMapController> _mapController = Completer();

      final CameraPosition _initialCamera = CameraPosition(
      target: LatLng(-20.3000, -40.2990),
      zoom: 14.0000,
      );
      var maptype = MapType.normal;
       @override
       Widget build(BuildContext context) {
       return Scaffold(
       resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,
      body: Stack(
       children: <Widget>[
        GoogleMap(
        mapType: maptype,
        initialCameraPosition: _initialCamera,
        onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
          _mapController.complete(controller);
        },
      ),
          
          ],
          ),

     floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
    backgroundColor: Colors.white,
    foregroundColor: Colors.black,
    child: const Icon(Icons.my_location),
    onPressed: () {
    setState(() {
      
      this.maptype=MapType.satellite;
    });
    },
  ),


            );
          }
          }
```

Comment: Just keep in mind that this reloads the map, thus probably counts as additional API calls and costs money on web.

Comment: @d0n.key could you explain more please?

Comment: @d0n.key is this is related to your comment `I/Counters(11854): exceeded sample count in FrameTime`

Answer (score 11):

1. Create a MapType variable:

   ```
   MapType _currentMapType = MapType.normal;
   ```
2. Reference this variable when calling your Google Map widget:

   ```
   googleMap = new GoogleMap(
       mapType: _currentMapType,  
       //etc
   ```
3. Create a floating button widget to toggle map types:

   ```
   floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(           
                             child: Icon(Icons.layers),
                             onPressed: ()=> 
                             {
                                setState(() {
                                   _currentMapType = (_currentMapType == MapType.normal) ? MapType.satellite : MapType.normal;  
                                });
                             },
                             heroTag: null,
                           ),
   ```